# How to show the form with the desktop background dimmed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show the winform to be displayed, however the form would be in the normal state (not maximized). However, i want to dim the desktop background to be dimmed for user attention.

Maximized form with background dimmed is an option, but i don't want to maximize the form.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate the UAC confirmation dialog behavior?

Comment: The best way to do this is to not do it. This is among the first "features" I disable on every new installation of Windows 7.

Comment: Ya, sort of UAC confirmation dialog behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maximized form with background dimmed is an option

Firstly if the form is maximised, then there is no point in doing anything with the background as it cannot be seen.

> i want to dim the desktop background to be dimmed for user attention

This is messing with the OS settings, and I am not even sure if it is possible *and* it is certainly *not* desirable. I, as a user, would *never* want an application messing with my other running programs or my OS settings/preferences.

In short what you want is not possible (at least with out some nasty code) and it is not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can change the background, as well as I dont think you should.

I'd try to open "maximized" form with large opaque (or half-transparent) border.

May be [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) will be helpful